# Computing difficult indefinite integral

Tags: integration

\begin{array}{l}{\text { Compute the following integral in the case that } n \text { is a positive integer. }} \\ \\ {\\\quad A(n, x)=\int \frac{x^{n} d x}{1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2 !}+\ldots+\frac{x^{n}}{n !}}, \quad \\  \text{Seems like the denominator has something to do with Taylor Series?} }\end{array}

Comment: Let $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{x^k}{k!}}$. Note that $\frac{x^n}{P_n(x)}=n!\left(1-\frac{P_n’(x)}{P_n(x)}\right)$. So $A(n,x)=n!x-n!\ln{P_n(x)}$.

Comment: What is the motivation behind the equality $\frac{x^n}{P_n(x)} = n!\left(1-\frac{P_n'(x)}{P_n(x)}\right)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac{x^n}{1+x+\cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}}
= n! - n!\cdot\frac{1+x+\cdots + \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}{1+x+\cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}}
$$
Now split up the integral and use a substitution on the second one.